# wampserver localhost does not opening

Tags: mysql, wampserver

I installed successfully  Wampserver 2.2a to my computer.
After I started the services, clicked to localhost
In my browser there is a message like

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server

what can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Is Wamp running on port 80? ( may try localhost:8080)

Comment: Did you change any file? Check access.log so you can see if you are reaching the server. PS. How did you click to localhost?

Comment: i clicked to localhost,  from WAMPSERVER service online, green icon...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running on Windows 7  it's possible that the installer changed your hosts file

only one entry:

127.0.0.1   localhost

should be there

http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,77924

Answer (score 0):

Schwarzie2478 answer did the trick for me!

If you're on Windows 7, try to reach 127.0.0.1 in your browser — if you can access 127.0.0.1 but localhost is not working, check your Windows hosts file at: C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc

Open the "hosts" file in notepad and make sure it contains one line:

127.0.0.1       localhost

Don't forget to save the file after you make changes. It's also wise to keep a copy/backup of your old "hosts" file.